# vb SerialPort one message behind

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I followed this tutorial to create a simple SerialPort monitor: http://www.innovatic.dk/knowledg/SerialCOM/SerialCOM.htm

I am expecting 15+ lines of messages, then a one second pause, then another 15+ lines of messages, etc.

```
Message 1, Line 1
Message 1, Line 2
Message 1, Line ...
Message 1, Line 14
Message 1, Line 15
.
.
(1 second pause)
.
.
Message 2, Line 1
Message 2, Line 2
Message 2, Line ...
Message 2, Line 14
Message 2, Line 15
```

The problem is that the final line in the first message gets displayed at the start of the second message:

```
Message 1, Line 1
Message 1, Line 2
Message 1, Line ...
Message 1, Line 14
.
.
(1 second pause)
.
.
Message 1, Line 15
Message 2, Line 1
Message 2, Line 2
Message 2, Line ...
Message 2, Line 14
```

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Receiver(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Try
        Me.BeginInvoke(New StringSubPointer(AddressOf Display), SerialPort1.ReadLine)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub Display(ByVal Buffer As String)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(Buffer)
            RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you,
Brett

Comment: The code as posted cannot produce the output, it strips the line endings.

Comment: Could you explain more? I do not understand what you mean by "it strips the line endings." Is there a better way of having an even driven serial port read?

Answer (score 0):

the reason can be the format of your input messages. if they are written with [newline char + message] then until unless another message comes read line function will not extract a line.
this explains the reason of getting the first 14 messages in both sets.

Comment: answering 7 year old questions! The original system was read by putty which worked fine. It wasn't until I wrote the VB code to read the serial port was there problems. I always suspected that I wasn't reading the serial buffer correctly as the newline char was at the end of each message. 7 years is a long time and I don't know if I ever got it working or not.

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, can you please provide a code fix to the explanation? It will help other users who ran into the same issue.

Comment: I didn't see 7 years thing :). while i was looking for a best way to read data from a modbus serial, found your question. 
answer depend of what type of data you trying to read. in my case it was modbus. so the best way is listen for the data receive event and read them in to an array using .BytesToRead method.